# TypeScript Compiler: TypeChecker#getTypeAtLocation() returns error for non-local types

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

I am working on some TypeScript tooling. For that I am using `TypeChecker#getTypeAtLocation()` to determine the type of a `PropertyDeclaration` that only has an `initializer` but no declared `type`. That works well for primitives (number, string etc.) and locally declared types. However, for imported types I always get an error type back. That makes sense to a degree because the imported type is not part of the current syntax tree, but it is also not helpful in many cases. What could be the problem, keeping mind that I run `tsc.js` within the JVM using Nashorn?

Comment: What's the result of [`ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/e8748f8162e85d85581cf2006e4cee51bf796e84/lib/typescript.d.ts#L4380)?

Comment: I don't have a `program`, I just use `ts.createSourceFile()` to get a syntax tree.

Comment: How did you get the `typeChecker` then? It comes from `program.getTypeChecker()`.

Comment: I just called `ts.createTypeChecker()`; apparently that's not good enough, but there no docs...

Comment: Yeah, that's not part of [the public api](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/typescript.d.ts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `TypeChecker` instance should only be used with the source files and descendant nodes that are found in the corresponding `Program` instance that type checker was created from.

The error type you are seeing happens because the source file will have not undergone the binding phase where symbols are created for it. Binding only happens to a `ts.SourceFile` when the type checker requests the source file via the program's `CompilerHost`.

When calling `TypeChecker#getTypeAtLocation`, it might internally attempt to get the symbol for that node. When it does this, it won't find the symbol and then return the error type. Calling this method works when providing string and number literals because the compiler doesn't need to look at the symbols to figure out the type in that case.

To fix this, get your source files from the `Program` instance (ex. by using `program.getSourceFiles()` or `program.getSourceFile(fileName)`) instead of the direct result of `ts.createSourceFile` (only provide that to the compiler host).

Comment: Thanks, that is very informative. So is idea the to call `createProgram()` with `rootNames` containing the paths of all involved TypeScript files?

Comment: @FelixM yes exactly. Or enough for it to figure out the other files based on the imports and exports of the provided root names.

Comment: @DavidSherret I am having the same problem in a ts-loader plugin I am developing. Is there a different way in getting the type checker in this case ?  I am getting the Type Checker by calling ```program.getTypeChecker()``` on the program instance passed to me from the plugin.